# How to specify range/domain [-1,1] where -1 and 1 are excluded?

Tags: functions

Assume I have the **tanh** function. The range is between 'approaches -1 and approaches 1' where -1 and 1 is excluded. In some publications I see this listed as range [-1,1], however this is wrong because -1 and 1 is not included.

How to specify this range correctly? In the Coursera Calcus MOOC of Jim Fowler I see he is using as range e.g. $$[0,\infty)$$

To mention that 0 is included (bracket), but infinity itself not (parenthesis).

So if I follow this approach than the correct range for tanh = (-1,1) which is everything between -1 and 1 but excluding those values itself.

Is this correct?

Comment: Absolutely. Most mathematitians would define $(a,b)$ to be the set $\{x\in\mathbb R: a<x<b\}$. Very rarely, the alternative notation is $]a,b[$

Comment: It's a question of countries... I know in anglophone literature, it is the parentheses, but for example, in France, the standard notation is with the open brackets. So it must change with the language...

Comment: In my education I think we used $]-1,1[$ but as 5xum says $(-1,1)$ seems to also be used.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct. Another common way of denoting the open interval $(0,1)$ is $]0,1[$.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you're right. In general, for specifying an interval of real numbers, a square bracket indicates that the endpoint is included, while a round bracket indicates that it is not.

The terminology used is that $[-1,1]$ is a **closed** interval, while $(-1,1)$ is an **open** interval.

Intervals like $(-1,1]$ and $[-1,1)$ are sometimes called **half-open**

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. In set builder notation:

$$(-1,1)=\{x\in \Bbb{R}\colon -1<x<1\}$$

This reads "the set of $x$ in $\Bbb{R}$ (the real numbers) such that $x$ is greater that $-1$ and less than $1$".

Another notation is $]-1,1[$ although this is less common.